# Responsive design with flexbox divs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following code for the center of my homepage. The issue is with responsiveness. When I resize the browser window the right div hides to the right (off-screen) and the center div remains centered (as I want it to be for any window size). The issue appears when the center div collides with the left div and it gets pushed off-center to the right. Is there any way to make the left div behave like the right one (hide off-screen to the left - which I don't think is possible)? I have tried applying `overflow: hidden` to hide the left div behind the center div but it doesn't look good. Any other ideas on how to make my design responsive?

```css
main {
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#left {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  animation: bounce_left 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

#center {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
}

#right {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: green;
  animation: bounce_right 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes bounce_left {
    0% {transform: translateX(-50px);}
    50% {transform: translateX(0px);}
    100% {transform: translateX(-50px);}
}
@keyframes bounce_right {
    0% {transform: translateX(50px);}
    50% {transform: translateX(0px);}
    100% {transform: translateX(50px);}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right now that's what it looks on mobile and tablet. What exactly do you want to achieve please https://prnt.sc/1xd0fua https://prnt.sc/1xd0ew3

Comment: the snippet didn`t actually play as my site does and it is kind of misleading...

Comment: ok so you solved your problem? mark you answer as the good one please.

Comment: I did but I can't mark my answer sooner than 2 days

Answer (score 0):

Making the snippet actually gave me the idea to make all three divs take 33.33% width space in a wrapper and because the left and right divs contain an image each I made the width of the left image to be `inherit` so now it just resizes on window resize. It actually gives it a design feature that I didn't even think about. I love this business.
This is the modified snippet in case it makes more sense:

```css
main {
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#left {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  animation: bounce_left 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

#center {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
}

#right {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: green;
  animation: bounce_right 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes bounce_left {
    0% {transform: translateX(-50px);}
    50% {transform: translateX(0px);}
    100% {transform: translateX(-50px);}
}
@keyframes bounce_right {
    0% {transform: translateX(50px);}
    50% {transform: translateX(0px);}
    100% {transform: translateX(50px);}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div id="left"><img src="" alt="" style="width: 100%"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="right"><img src="" alt="" style="width: 100%"></div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I rescale my browser window the left div image resizes as well.

Comment: Interesting! Can you please include the code in your answer to make things clearer?